# Boost thread issue, how to share variable when one thread doesn't have the same copy as another?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, shared-variable

This is probably a silly question but I did search all over the internet about variables and found everything related to mutexes and racing conditions, locks, etc; but nothing that seems to solve this simple problem.

Basically the code below create two threads and in each thread the variable `shared_int` is changed to represent the thread it is used in. The threads run separately and the class itself seems to have two instances of the same variable `shared_int` in two different threads? The problem I have is that I want this variable to be altered in either thread  and readable as well, but I also want the value of `shared_int` seen from one thread to be the same in the second thread. Here's the code

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

template <typename I>
class threaded
{
    private:

        I volatile shared_int;

    public:

        threaded();
        virtual ~threaded();
        bool inputAvailable();
        void thread_1();
        void thread_2();
};

template <typename I>
threaded<I>::threaded(){}

template <typename I>
threaded<I>::~threaded(){}

template <typename I>
bool threaded<I>::inputAvailable()
{
      struct timeval tv;
      fd_set fds;
      tv.tv_sec = 0;
      tv.tv_usec = 0;
      FD_ZERO(&fds);
      FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
      select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

      return (FD_ISSET(0, &fds));
}

template <typename I>
void threaded<I>::thread_1()
{
    shared_int = 1;

    while(!inputAvailable())
    {
        std::cout<<"threaded::thread_1 shared_int "<<this->shared_int<<std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for( boost::chrono::milliseconds{ 9000});
    };
}

template <typename I>
void threaded<I>::thread_2()
{
    shared_int = 2;

    while(!inputAvailable())
    {
        std::cout<<"threaded::thread_2 shared_int "<<this->shared_int<<std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for( boost::chrono::milliseconds{ 10000});
    };
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group thread;
    threaded< int> threads;

    thread.add_thread( new boost::thread( boost::bind( &threaded<int>::thread_1, threads)));
    thread.add_thread( new boost::thread( boost::bind( &threaded<int>::thread_2, threads)));

    thread.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run the code. If you run it you'll see that `thread_1` outputs `1` for `shared_int` unlike for `thread_2` which outputs `2` for `shared_int`?

Comment: So `bind` does something funny, I know that it creates multiple copies when you pass an object into it but I didn't think it would cause this problem. Should I use shared pointers or is there a way to not use `bind` with threads?

Answer (score 0):

This code below does seem to solve the problem. It uses `boost::shared_ptr` but it also works with regular pointers; either way! I would still like a solution that passes objects **by value** instead of pointers just for the hell of it but pointers work for now.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

template <typename I>
class threaded
{
    private:

        I volatile shared_int;

    public:

        threaded();
        virtual ~threaded();
        bool inputAvailable();
        void thread_1();
        void thread_2();
};

template <typename I>
threaded<I>::threaded(){}

template <typename I>
threaded<I>::~threaded(){}

template <typename I>
bool threaded<I>::inputAvailable()
{
      struct timeval tv;
      fd_set fds;
      tv.tv_sec = 0;
      tv.tv_usec = 0;
      FD_ZERO(&fds);
      FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
      select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

      return (FD_ISSET(0, &fds));
}

template <typename I>
void threaded<I>::thread_1()
{
    shared_int = 1;

    while(!inputAvailable())
    {
        std::cout<<"threaded::thread_1 shared_int "<<this->shared_int<<std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for( boost::chrono::milliseconds{ 9000});
    };
}

template <typename I>
void threaded<I>::thread_2()
{
    shared_int = 2;

    while(!inputAvailable())
    {
        std::cout<<"threaded::thread_2 shared_int "<<this->shared_int<<std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for( boost::chrono::milliseconds{ 10000});
    };
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group thread;
    boost::shared_ptr< threaded <int> > threads{ new threaded <int>};

    thread.add_thread( new boost::thread( boost::bind( &threaded<int>::thread_1, threads)));
    thread.add_thread( new boost::thread( boost::bind( &threaded<int>::thread_2, threads)));

    thread.join_all();
    threads.reset();

    return 0;
}
```